# Proving that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\frac1{nx}dx \neq 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

**Problem:**

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{nx}$ for $x\in[1, \infty)$. Show that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = 0$$ but $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty f_n(x)dx \neq 0.$$

**My progress:**

The first limit was rather trivial given that x is positive.

For the second limit, I have come as far as to integrate $f_n(x)$, which yielded

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac1n \left[ \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\ln(x)\right]\right]$$

Right now, I have a $0\cdot\infty$ expression, which I suppose can be said to be *not zero*, but it seems cheap.

I also contemplated, since both limits tend to infinity, switch x with n, so that we have $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \cdot \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\ln(n)$$

I tried L'Hopital on this, but that gave me 0, which is clearly not what I want.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: $\int_1^{+\infty}1/(nx)\,dx=+\infty$ for all $n=1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: Are you sure that the integral is from $1$ to $\infty$, not to $n$ ?

Comment: @larry01 - Yes, it was infinity explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the improper Riemann sense you are dealing with:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_1^b \frac{1}{nx} dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( \frac{1}{n} \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_1^b \frac{1}{x} dx \right ).$$

The point of the exercise is that you cannot exchange the two limits. But the situation is simpler than you are making it, because $\int_1^b \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln(b)$. So the inner limit is always $+\infty$ regardless of the value of $n$. This means the outer limit is also $+\infty$.

What you did towards the end is a *very* different calculation; you showed that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_1^n \frac{1}{x} dx = 0.$$

This takes the limit in $b$ *simultaneously* with the limit in $n$.

Comment: I can see that there is a core concept here that I'm not familiar with. Why do you not end up with $0\cdot\infty$ when $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Alec Do you see the parentheses in Ian's first equation here? You have to do $+\infty$ times $\frac{1}{n}$ *before* you take the limit $n\to+\infty$. And $+\infty$ times $\frac{1}{n}$ is $+\infty$. (In whatever extended reals we have to do that kind of arithmetic.)

Comment: @Alec The indeterminate form $0 \cdot \infty$ arises when you have $a_n$ and $b_n$ which are *both* finite, such that $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to \infty$, and you are considering the limit of $a_n b_n$. But if $a_n$ is finite and never zero and $b_n$ is always $\infty$, then the sequence $a_n b_n$ is just the sequence $\infty,\infty,\infty,\dots$ forever.

Comment: @whacka - Yes, however, I can't entirely grasp it. It looks like he's absorbing the 1/n into the infinity of the integral, which renders $n\to\infty$ pointless.

Comment: @Alec Once you've done the integrals, you're dealing with a sequence of *numbers*, all of which are $+\infty$.

Comment: @Alec: Of course he's absorbing the 1/n into the infinity, that's what I just said, that's what you can and have to do. The problem isn't exactly pointless if it managed to trip you up, is it? :-) Let me ask you this: can you determine the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\lim\limits_{y\to0} xy)$? (Ian: nevermind about your comment, I didn't see that you set $b_n\color{Red}{=}\infty$.)

Comment: @Ian - Thanks! I now have the answer, and the steps to get there. However, the idea of one limit rendering the other redundant, is new to me. I fully expected the indeterminate form here. Do you know where I can read up on this concept?

Comment: @Alec You already know the concept: **order of operations**. You **evaluate things inside parentheses before** incorporating it into other things. For instance to find $(2+1)^2$, you wouldn't square $2$ and *then* add $1$, you would add $2$ and $1$ together and *then* square.

Comment: @whacka - I think the source of my struggles here was the fact that I was completely oblivious to the idea of one limit being prioritized, such that it "absorbed" the variable for the other.

Comment: @Ian - Brilliant! And I'm an idiot!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\underbrace{\color{#05f}{\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx}}_{\to \infty} = \infty $$

$$\color{#05f}{\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx} = \ln x \Big|_1^\infty \to \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_1^\infty\frac1{nx}dx=\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\right)\int_1^\infty\frac1{x}dx.$$

If the integral converges (which it doesn't), the limit is $0$. Otherwise it doesn' t exist.